# STM32F7_Discovery_Boards Digital Pin

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

Do any of the pins on CN9 or CN13 on the STM32F7 Discovery Board have a constant 3.3 or 5V output?

Comment: When you say "digital pins" do you mean the GPIO, or any available pin?

Comment: Sorry the Arduino connectors on the right side CN9 or CN13 ?

Comment: i think that you should be asking if there are any power pins on the board .... `digital pins` usually refers to data pins

Comment: Identify which STM32F7 discovery board.  The answer depends on how you power your board.  USB is meant to power these boards, but if you provide external power, you have 5V at USB connector.  It is how USB works.

Comment: So my question should have been does this board have constant voltage at the Arduino pins are they constantly on like on a TI board. - anyway

Answer (score 0):

> Do any of the digital pins on the STM32F7 Discovery Boards have a constant 3.3 or 5 V output?

Yes.

ST publishes datasheets for the STM32x microcontrollers as well as overviews, manuals, and summaries of the Discovery kits. For example, the [STM32F723 eval board has this data brief](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/data_brief/group1/3c/a9/04/27/16/f6/4a/4c/DM00342313/files/DM00342313.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00342313.pdf).

[image: STM32F723IE Discovery Kit Data Brief]

---

Note that this may not be true of ***all*** STM32F7x discovery kits.